# How to read no. pixels per res. unit in TIFF header

Tags: header, io, tiff

I'm trying to read a TIFF image that has been exported from a Leica (SP5) program. I can read other details (e.g. bits per sample, image size x, image size y) as per tags defined in TIFF documentation. I'm sort of crudely reading the header out as unsigned integers until I get to a certain tag number.

I know at 296, my 'Resolution Unit' is cm. At 282 and 283, it's supposed to give me the number of pixels (in x and y) per resolution unit. I'm not sure how to do this. Can someone please help??

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Interactive Data Language. It's based on Fortran. I don't really need the code, just the basic idea. Am I reading the header using the wrong data type? How am I supposed to get the dword numerator and dword denominator (as it says in the TIFF header documentation)? Sorry, I'm new at this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if at 296 you discover what the unit type is (either 1 - No absolute  unit, 2 - Inch, or 3 - Centimeter) and at 282 and 283 you get XResolution and YResolution respectively then you have everything you need to solve the problem.

To get a per unit type measure just multiply XResolution and YResolution together:

```
XResolution * YResolution = PixelsPerUnit
```

Since you are trying to find the area of the rectangle created by the resolutions.

Comment: Yes - I am aware, but apparently at 282 and 283, you have to read two dwords and divide them to get the number of pixels per unit. I don't know how to read out two dwords. I've tried to read in various data types at tag 282 and do not come up with the number of pixels per unit that I expect.

Comment: I am wondering whether I am reading it wrong OR the pixels per unit isn't actually stored there (for example, if the Leica software does not export a proper TIFF). However, I know that the information is in the header somewhere because I can open the TIFF in ImageJ and get it to read out the no. pixels per unit. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, a dword is 4 bytes (32 bits) so you'll have to find a corresponding variable in your language. "read two dwords and divide them", I don't see why you'd divide in this calculation. It's just multiplication. What are the numbers you are seeing in 282 and 283? What are you expecting for pixels per units?

Comment: (1) TIFF header info I just got off here: http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/corion.htm Says that a rational field type consists of two dwords, one a numerator and one a denominator (scroll down tiny bit to the second "table" to see this) and then when you go to the label description (search it), it says it's a rational field, so I assumed that's what it meant.

Comment: (2) If I'm reading out as unsigned integers (16-bit) I get: [282,5,1,0,270,16,283...]. If instead I read 2 32-bit integers after the 282 tag (as per 'dword'), I get either [282,65541,24248320,16,283...] or [282,5,1,1048946,283...] depending on which bits I take (I hope this part makes sense).

I am expecting 52851.61 pixels per resolution unit. The resolution unit is cm, which I have successfully retrieved from 296 as '3'.

Comment: Hi all, still need help with this.

Comment: A TIFF tag consists of 12 bytes: 2-byte tag number, 2-byte data type, 4-byte count and 4-byte payload. If the payload won't fit in 4-bytes then the payload is an offset which points to the data somewhere else in the file. In your case, 2 32-bit longs are what make up a rational (8-bytes), so tags 282 and 283 each contain offsets to 8-bytes of data elsewhere in the file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So e.g. at tag 282:
data type: 5
count: 1, 0
payload: 270, 16

Do I go look at 270? 16? 27016?

Thanks.